# Best mid to high range camera nowadays to use for shooting big farm equipment

Tags: wide-angle

I am a graphic designer and I do a bit of photography but not on an expert level so I thought I'd ask here for I'm sure I will get a lot of insights. What is the best mid to high range cameras nowadays for shooting big farm equipment in the field? And what lenses as well? Also I am deciding between DSLR and mirrorless. The main purpose of the camera is for taking pictures, and video is secondary but it would be nice to have the capability of both still photo and video.

I provided an image to show what kind of pictures I am taking. Keep in mind though I do not own the photo. Thanks everyone!

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118540/discussion-on-question-by-foreverlearner4-best-mid-to-high-range-camera-nowadays).

Answer (score 2):

The situation you have is not a big deal in terms of a camera. As you can read in the comments any camera, including a phone will give you decent images.

The situation you have is good natural light and a lot of space to move around. You will be fine with the kit zoom lens until you know a bit more about the limitations of it.

But let's try to narrow it from the Designers point of view, mainly Resolution.

A normal standard for DSLR nowadays is 24Mpx that will give you more than enough for an A3 or Tabloid size print for a brochure. But if you need photos for a website you can have a lot less resolution.

And most modern cameras have video capabilities. Look for one that can shoot at least 60 fps so you can have some room for a slow-motion effect.

There are a lot of threads talking about a general guide to decide what camera to buy. It narrows on what you need, what you like, and what is your budget.

Probably you need just a good DSLR instead of a more pricey Mirrorless and save some bucks for a drone. So, define your objectives.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed input!  Can you recommend a camera that can take a lot of beating? What I mean is during summer, I usually go out and run around the field and take pictures of farm equipment moving, so there's dust, etc. Will a DSLR work or should I go for mirrorless ones?  Also if you can recommend a good affordable lenses for my purposes that would be great.